# Indesign Document Blacked Out

Tags: adobe-indesign

I was working within my Indesign document and must have accidentally hit a key that turned the background of my document black while also hiding all of my guides and text/images boxes.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!! [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my InDesign preview mode background turn black?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66665/why-did-my-indesign-preview-mode-background-turn-black)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in black is not your document, but a virtual container around your document. Kind of like the table your book sits on top of.

Accidentally you may have hit <kbd>W</kbd> which activates this 'Preview' mode. In which case just hit <kbd>W</kbd> again and you're back to the initial situation.

Another likely shortcut you may have hit is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which does the same but in full screen mode.